# "Unresolved variable" when using className={styles.nameOfClass}

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to change a button's style in ReactJS with the "className" element.  However, I get back an error stating "Unresolved variable nameOfClass" in WebStorm, and the stylistic changes are not made when I run webpack and open the page on localhost.  I have attempted different methods of importing the CSS file and naming conventions to no avail.

The file with the React Component class is here:

```
import * as React from "react";
var styles = require('./Roster.css');
export class Roster extends React.Component<{},{}> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className={styles.nameOfClass} type="button" >Players</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the Roster.css file is here:

```
.nameOfClass {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",
    externals: ['axios'],
    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/,
              loader: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'),
            }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css', { allChunks: true })
    ],

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

Comment: Are you using any css loaders in webpack?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post to include the webpack.config.js

Comment: It looks like a bug in Webstorm. I'm using css-modules and am getting these warnings also when I add classes and import them, but the styles render correctly and eslint and stylelint are fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like:

```
import * as React from "react";

export class Roster extends React.Component<{},{}> {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <button className="nameOfClass" type="button">Players</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

You can't require css files, only typescript/javascript files.

There's the [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) thing, and there are some js solutions for react/css, such as [Radium](http://stack.formidable.com/radium/) and [reactCss](http://reactcss.com).

Comment: This is not true. You can import css files into your JS to use like he did above

Comment: @erichardson30 I've never used it, so I might be wrong, but as I understand it you need something extra to use css-modules and the OP did not show any hint of him using that.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, do you know what the extra plugin is that I would need to use for that?

Comment: Nope. I've never used any of those.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to require the styles file.

```
import * as React from "react";

export class Roster extends React.Component<{},{}> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="nameOfClass" type="button" >Players</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and your css file:

```
.nameOfClass {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: How will the file know the origin of "nameOfClass" if I have no way of calling that other file?

Comment: I reference my css files in my index.html (or .ejs, or whatever you use)